# Imagemagick change label font and squash

Tags: image, fonts, command, imagemagick

Is it possible to change the font of a label?

I have following command:

```
> convert -background none -bordercolor none -gravity west -fill white
> img1.png label:"1" -border 0x5 +swap -append -font "Helvetica-LT-55-Roman" label:"Chapter 1" -border
> 0x5 -append -write miff:- +delete img2.png label:"2" -border 0x5 +swap
> -append label:"Chapter 2" -border 0x5 -append -write miff:- +delete img3.png label:"3" -border 0x5 +swap -append label:"Chapter 3" -border
> 0x5 -append -write miff:- +delete img4.png label:"4" -border 0x5 +swap
> -append label:"Chapter 4" -border 0x5 -append -write miff:- +delete img5.png label:"5" -border 0x5 +swap -append label:"Chapter 5" -border
> 0x5 -append miff:- | montage -set label "" miff:- -tile 3x2 -geometry
> +15-10 -background none result.png
```

which creates me an image with 5 image, each image has a text above and under.

If I:

```
convert -list font
```

it does show me the font I want to use.

Thus is there a way to squash the label(text) width?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make your examples simpler!

Do you want to know how to change the font of a label? Or do you want to know how to crop a label's width?

If you list your fonts like this:

```
identify -list font
```

**Output**

```
  Font: Palatino-Bold
    family: Palatino
    style: Normal
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 700
    glyphs: /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/p052004l.pfb
  Font: Palatino-BoldItalic
    family: Palatino
    style: Italic
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 700
    glyphs: /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/p052024l.pfb
  Font: Palatino-Italic
    family: Palatino
    style: Italic
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 400
    glyphs: /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/p052023l.pfb
  Font: Palatino-Roman
    family: Palatino
    style: Normal
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 400
    glyphs: /usr/local/share/ghostscript/fonts/p052003l.pfb
```

You can then create a label with a `Palatino-Italic` font and trim it like this:

```
convert -undercolor yellow -pointsize 36 -font Palatino-Italic label:"Palatino-Italic" -trim result.png
```

[image]

Comment: sorry I used the wrong term, I mean squash instead of crop

Answer (score 0):

What does "squash" mean? Please define or provide an example of such a process.

If you mean distort the image to have a smaller width, then you can use -resize to do so. For example to reduce the width by half and keep the height the same, use -resize 50x100%